# Getting "Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure:" error while trying to run rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I am getting the following error for the all rspec tests, which have been working fine before...  Really strange thing is that I didn't change anything with regard to mongod or rspec or mongoid...  :(  I can access mongo shell just fine, too.

Any help or suggestion for debugging this would be much appreciated!

- Ruby: 1.9.3p194
- Rails: 3.2.12
- Mongod: 2.2
- Mongoid: 3.1.4

`Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure:
       Could not connect to a primary node for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address=nil>]>`

Link to mongoid.yml: https://gist.github.com/yangtheman/5879742

Comment: Can you display your mongoid.yml?

Comment: @Rebitzele, sure. I just updated the post with a gist link to [mongoid.yml](https://gist.github.com/yangtheman/5879742). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is too embarrassing, but I found the source of the error.  I somehow commented out localhost line in hosts file.  When I uncommented it, everything went back to normal.